# Python and SharePoint. Share file via api

Tags: python, api, sharepoint, python-requests, sharepoint-api

I'm automating the sharing process in sharepoint using python, and was wondering how one would do to share (ie: give editing permissions) a specific file (using file-url as input) with a specific person.

I successfully was able to authenticate myself using HttpNtlmAuth, but have a hard time figuring out which api requests to do.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: grammar

Answer (score 0):

You may have a try this undocumented endpoint:

- [Sharing Documents with the SharePoint REST API](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2014/09/sharing-documents-with-sharepoint-rest.html)
- [DocumentSharingManager.UpdateDocumentSharingInfo method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/jj170080(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

I have tried the above JS and it works well.